# Is there any trigger run before dynamic sql (as execute immediate or dbms_sql.execute)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm creating a feature to allow user create proceduce, function, package and run they with some permissions (grant by this program, not database permission) save in a table.

I want create a trigger run before any dynamic SQL and analyse it to prevent dangerous SQL statements from bad users? Like following

```
  +------------+ 
  |   PROGRAM  |------------------------------+
  +------------+                              |
         |                                    |
         v                                    |   
  +------------+      +------------+     +---------------+
  | USER'S SQL |      | PERMISSION |     |  SESSION INFO |
  +------------+      +------------+     +---------------+
         |___________________|________________|
         v
  +-----------------+
  |     TRIGGER     |-------------+
  +-----------------+             |
         | Allow                  | Not allow
         v                        v
+-----------------------+   +-------------+
|   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE   |   |    ERROR    |
+-----------------------+   +-------------+
```

Can I create anythings like this?

Comment: Is your diagram correct?  I understood your design to be that users would pass their SQL *into* your program which would then use Dynamic SQL to run the statement.  If this is the case then your program can contain your logic for 'dangerous SQL' and can conditionally execute.  I am really interested in how you are going to define and identify 'dangerous SQL'

Comment: Why do you try to reinvent the wheel, use Oracle permissions. Or make all operations through PL/SQL procedures (i.e. grant nothing but EXECUTE on your procedures). Inside your procedure you can do whatever you want.

Comment: You can use `before` trigger on `database`. However, I agree with previous comments that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Plus, triggers are evil.

Comment: There is only 1 user Oracle and it doesn't have create user or alter user privilege. I want share it for my customers, but these customers have difference privilege. I have 2 approachs: 1. create a trigger to limit user permission, 2. create privilege per session. But, I don't know Oracle has any technology like that. And of course, it is not possible to create a bunch of database users, eg: 1000000 DB users for 1000000 APP users, which would be a waste of DB resources and not possible to manage them.

Comment: maybe you need a validator program, that could be a database procedure that validates users's sql and decide whether to execute the user's sql or not

Comment: Are there anyone know enterprise user security, how can I implement it. It seems like what I want.